# downloading and installing a program with the code

Tags: python, wget

I need to download and install a program with the python code, I figured out how to download, however, there are problems in the installation process. The code is the following

```
import platform
import os
import wget

url_windows='https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/13.0.1+9/cec27d702aa74d5a8630c65ae61e4305/jdk-13.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe'
url_mac='https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/13.0.1+9/cec27d702aa74d5a8630c65ae61e4305/jdk-13.0.1_osx-x64_bin.dmg'
url_linux='https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/13.0.1+9/cec27d702aa74d5a8630c65ae61e4305/jdk-13.0.1_linux-x64_bin.deb'

if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    installer=wget.download(url_windows)
if platform.system()== 'Linux':
    installer=wget.download(url_linux)
if platform.system() == 'Mac':
    installer=wget.download(url_mac)

path=os.path.abspath(installer)

f=open(path)
```

As in the path the username consists of whitespace and the error occurs.

Comment: you don't need to convert the path to string. throw out ``str``

Comment: I thought that would help, but it's not working either

Comment: What error? I bet dollars to donuts that the error has nothing to do with spaces in the path.

Comment: If you run it from cmd or a terminal, share the error message here. I've never seen a module named platform for python. You probably want this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?highlight=sys#sys.platform

Comment: Why do you mention a username at the end?

Comment: it returner Syntax error, pointing to the whitespace in the path.

Comment: @MadPhysicist the whitespace is in the username, I think the problem is that the problem is with the link as the website doesn't allow to download without agreeing to the license agreement. Do you know a solution?

Comment: There's no username anywhere in your code and you really need to post the full error with trace in your question.

Comment: Probably  I should not have written the username(username is in the path)

Comment: You should post the error instead of guessing.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I understood the error. If you don't mind, can I please contact you somehow and ask a few questions?

Comment: **Post** the error please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use os.system(path) or os.startfile(path) to launch an executable. The open command opens a file and returns a python object, which is not what you want in this case.